# React Native Map testing

Tags: jestjs

I've been attempting to get this test working but am having trouble transforming files into JS, Is anybody able to point me in the correct direction and how to diagnose it better next time? Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const MapComponent = ({ onRegionChange }) => {
  return (
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      onRegionChange={onRegionChange}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
});

export default MapComponent;
```

My Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import MapComponent from '../components/MapComponent';

test('MapComponent renders correctly', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<MapComponent />);
  const mapElement = getByTestId('map-element');
  expect(mapElement).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Error message:

```
FAIL  ./MapComponet.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies 
use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such 
syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files 
into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see 
https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-
```

started#using-typescript
• To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a
custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
• If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your
config.
• If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can
stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

```
    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/christiegriffiths/Desktop/skateApp/Bounty/node_modules/react-native- 
 maps/lib/MapView.js:344
                return (<decorateMapComponent_1.ProviderContext.Provider value=. 
{this.props.provider}>
                        ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      1 | import React from 'react';
      2 | import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    > 3 | import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
        | ^
      4 |
      5 | const MapComponent = ({ onRegionChange }) => {
      6 |   return (

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode 
(../../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest- 
runtime/build/index.js:1496:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/index.js:33:32)
      at Object.require (frontend/components/MapComponent.js:3:1)
      at Object.require (frontend/spec/MapComponet.test.js:3:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.75 s
```

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "bounty",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.3.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```